# Hyper-V VHD Expand and keeping snapshots?

Tags: hyper-v, vhd

I have a Virtual Machine and it includes OS and other programs of course. ATM I have around 5 Snapshots.

The Disk Space is running low and I wanted to expand the VHD. I enter VM's settings and intend to edit the VHD and expand the VHD but all i found was this messege.

[image]

So are there other ways of expanding a VHD?
I simple wondered if there is a way to keep the snapshots and expand the virtual hard disk. I realize that there might be problems if i remove them and then import them again.

Thanks for reading, George

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove your snapshots and then expand the disk. You should read up on how snapshots work, because that will explain why expanding the underlying VHD will be bad news for the delta disks.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I could figured as much, my question was maybe badly asked. I simple wondered if there is a way to keep the snapshots and expand the virtual hard disk. I realize that there might be problems if i remove them and then import them again.

Comment: No, basically - not without extreme risk. Snapshots should only be used temporarily or on development/testing machines anyway.

Comment: @George No worries, sorry it wasn't better news. It hurts me to say this - but you could maybe add a second VHD and Software RAID it. I take no responsibility for the resulting fires

Answer (score 0):

It may not have been possible when the original answer was written, but you can merge your snapshots into a new VHDX.

1. Look up the path to the disk image for the snapshot you want to expand in the snapshot settings.
2. Using the Hyper-V Manager -> Action -> Edit Disk, select the snapshot .avhx file.
3. Through the wizard, choose to merge the snapshot disk to a new dynamic .vhdx image. You should be able to configure a new size at this point.
4. When it's done, you can change your snapshot settings to point to the new .vhdx image.